# PL/SQL Script to create a procedure to calculate and return the area of a triangle

Tags: sql, oracle, function, stored-procedures, plsql

Hello guys i really need some help with oracle procedures and functions, I am a newbie in Oracle RDBMS and I can't seem to get the hang of it. Here is the question:
Define the Oracle PL/SQL script to create a procedure to calculate the area of a triangle:
1. Assuming it's a right angled triangle.
2. Assuming you have only been given the lengths of each if the 3 sides.

---

This one works, although I could not find how to embed a procedure to it:

```
declare
base integer;
height integer;
area integer;
BEGIN
height:= 12;
base := 10;
dbms_output.put_line('Height = '||height);
dbms_output.put_line('Base = '||base);
area := 0.5 * base * height;

dbms_output.put_line('The area of the triangle is ' ||area);
end;
```

Comment: Assuming you'll tell us where you're stuck ?

Comment: i dont know how to create such kind of a procedure

Comment: If you don't know how to create a procedure, [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-PROCEDURE.html#GUID-771879D8-BBFD-4D87-8A6C-290102142DA3) is what you need; If you have an issue with your code, please post your attempt, explaining us what's going wrong

Comment: okay thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function which uses [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Triangle#Computing_the_area_of_a_triangle):

```
create or replace function area_of_triangle 
   ( a in number, b in number, c in number)
   return number 
is
    s number;
    t_area number;
begin
    -- calculate semiperimeter
    s := (a + b + c) / 2;

    -- calculate area
    t_area := sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c) );

    return t_area;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you..I also found out the following snippet that is working, is it possible to embed in a procedure?

Comment: Your question says you are given the lengths of the three sides. That's why I suggested Heron's Formula. But if you're given height and base instead then it's simple enough to create a function using my answer as a template: you need two parameters not three, and the calculation is a single stage because you don't need to derive `s`.